# How to solve this entropy optimization problem with gradient projection method?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The problem is defined as
$$
\min_{w} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{3}w_kP_{ij}^{(k)}\right) \log \left(\sum_{k=1}^{3}w_kP_{ij}^{(k)}\right) \right\} + \gamma \|w\|_2^2\\
$$
and the constraints are
$$
w_k\gt 0,~~\sum_{k=1}^{3} w_k = 1
$$
where $w=[w_1, w_2, w_3]^T \in R^{3\times 1}$ and $0\le P_{ij}^{(k)} \le 1$.

My basic idea on this problem is as follows:

1. the gradient on $w_k$ is
   $$
   \nabla_{w_{k}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left\{P_{ij}^{(k)} \log \left(\sum_{k'=1}^{3}w_{k'} P_{ij}^{(k') } \right) +  P_{ij}^{(k)} \right\}+2\gamma w_k
   $$

then, I don't know how to do next. How could I solve this problem with the gradient projection method? Or could you help provide some references on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You need a *projected* gradient algorithm at the very least to handle the simplex constraint. Straight gradient will fail.

Comment: Hi, Prof. @MichaelGrant, thank you! I'm trying to solve this problem with the Lagrangian method.